# filtering kml in a static map

Tags: windows, kml

i'm developing a **desktop** application, **not web**.
The software environment is Windows and VB10.
In my user interface I have a browser where I want to show a map, issuing an address like http://maps.google.com/maps?q= and then I indicate a URL where I have put a KML file with my data.
The problem is: is it possible to filter the data in the KML file in order to show only a subset of them ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two options:

1. Pass parameters to a service which generates your filtered KML on the fly.
2. Do it in JavaScript in your browser interface.

Based on your question, I am going to assume option one is out. For option two there are tons of examples on the web, but basically you need to parse the KML yourself and write JavaScript code to handle it however it needs to be done to achieve your filtering, you cannot pass the KML URL to google maps directly and achieve any of this behaviour.

Possibly useful example: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/examples/google_folders.html

**UPDATE**

Based on conversation in the comments:

The only other thing I can think of is to create your own map page with the JavaScript to do what you want on it (like http://gpsvisualizer.com/examples/google_folders.html linked above) and then embedding it in your app instead of the google map. Essentially encapsulating the features you want. So instead of **maps.google.com/maps?q=** in your app you have **myMapURL.com/MyMap?querystring** which is your google maps wrapper with the desired filtering. Otherwise I think you are out of luck based on your current setup.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already considered option1, but it is not feasible for security problems. I would like to follow option2, but my application is VB, so how can I use javascript ? I can parse the KML in VB of course, but then how can I pass the result to google maps ?

Comment: Does the embedded browser you are using to display the map not support JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like not support javascript. I'm using a component named "system.windows.form.webbrowser": it is the one available in the main toolbox of vb10. Maybe it's time to switch to a web application, i fear ...

Comment: What is the security risk of providing filter inputs to the service which generates your KML if you are already providing a URL to a static KML document? Option one is how I have handled this multiple times.

Comment: I would like to make it that way, but my application will run on a PC that would not have access to the web server where the kml file is published ... they will be in two different organizations ...

Comment: So how are you accessing the KML without filtering? Note that if the URL for the KML is not publicly accessible, Google Maps will not load it either. Note will it allow you to load locally available KML files in the manner. In both cases you will require JavaScript to parse and set the data on the map.

Comment: hello Matthew, thx for your answers. The URL where the KML are, is publicly accessible, but I cannot write file in it at runtime, so I cant produce dynamic KML and see the results on my map. The reason is that my desktop application run on a different site and doees not have write permission on that URL.

Comment: And you are able to embed the map without Javascript?

Comment: yes, I have done a prototype in VB10 and it works, but I want make it doing better. The problem is the limit in the string you can pass allowing you only 2048 characters: this in practice means no more than 10 markers. That's the reason why I want to change the way, and pass the entire KML, but filtering it before show ...   If you are interested I can show you how my VB works, of course.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to create your own map page with the JavaScript to do what you want on it (like http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/examples/google_folders.html linked above) and then embedding it in your app instead of the google map. Essentially encapsulating the features you want. So instead of http://maps.google.com/maps?q= in your app you have http://myMapURL which is your google maps wrapper with the desired filtering. Otherwise I think you are out of luck based on your current setup.